# How to give the white space in between the alphabets in name field?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have tried by using the below code but it allows white space in starting and of the name field.  What I need is white space should not be in starting and end of the name field.

```
if(!$("#first").val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$')){
    $("#error_msg").empty().text("invalid");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. The pattern `^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$` is anchored to the beginning and end, so it can’t allow anything before or after this, and it allows for lower or upper case English letters only. This does not allow any white space.

Comment: In AngularJS, that could happen. Perhaps, you manipulate the text before validating. Please post the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i need how to give the whitespace after the alphabets and also it should not be in first and last

Comment: @tamil [edit] your question and add some examples of valid and invalid input. That might help us better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you do not edit the question, it will most likely to be closed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include a space inside square brackets

```
        if(!$("#first").val().match('^[a-zA-Z/ ]{3,16}$'))
        {
            $("#error_msg").empty().text("invalid");
            console.log('false');
        }
```

Comment: but the space should not be a last and first position character